# How to add description on tooltip in your code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

How to Add description of your code in tooltip in code editor like this:- [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf2Kk.png)

Is this possible in VS or VS code?

Comment: The tooltip is obscuring _exactly_ how you do that - metadata in comments.

Comment: Just edit the text that you see after `@brief` , So you can change "This is a function" for example to "This is my description, blah blah"

Comment: @user20716902 which compiler is this? i had taken image from internet so i don't know which compiler is this

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can do this by writing xml comments:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/examples

When something is commented like this, then it'll be shown as on image you shared.